# How to use web.py checkbox groups

Tags: python, html, web.py

I have a small form that I am using to allow the user to select a group of continents they wish to interact with. My form is defined like this

```
search_form = form.Form( 
    form.Textbox('search_country', description='Country', placeholder='Country to search'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='Africa'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='Antarctica'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='Asia'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='Australia'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='Europe'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='North America'),
    form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='South America'),
)
```

I render the elements separately using this [tutorial](http://webpy.org/cookbook/form_fields) because I am using the Twitter Bootstrap switch to make the check boxes sliders (expected output below).

This is done by this:

```
sidebarsearch_form = search_form()
countrySearch = sidebarsearch_form.search_country.render()
continentSearch = sidebarsearch_form.search_continent.render()
formhtml = unicode(render.searchform(searchcountry=countrySearch, searchcontinent=continentSearch))
```

My template looks like this

```
$def with (searchcountry,searchcontinent,form='')
<form method="GET" id="search-form">
<fieldset class="fieldset-grp">
    <label>Country</label>
    <div class="form-search">
        <div class="input-append">
            $:searchcountry[0]
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Continent</label>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Africa" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Antarctica" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Asia" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Australia" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Europe" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="North America" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
    <div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="South America" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        $:searchcontinent
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The output *looks* as I expect

[image: Output]

However, the HTML generated by this is not what I expect.

All of my check boxes look like this

```
<div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Africa" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        <input type="checkbox" id="search_continent_Africa" value="Africa" name="search_continent"/>
</div>
<div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Antarctica" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        <input type="checkbox" id="search_continent_Africa" value="Africa" name="search_continent"/>
</div>
<div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Asia" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        <input type="checkbox" id="search_continent_Africa" value="Africa" name="search_continent"/>
</div>
<div class="make-switch span11" data-on="success" data-text-label="Australia" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
        <input type="checkbox" id="search_continent_Africa" value="Africa" name="search_continent"/>
</div>
```

Notice that the `id` and `value` attributes of each are set to `search_continent_Africa` and `Africa` respectively.

The reason the screenshot has the correct values is because the bootstrap `switch` plugin uses the `data-text-label` to display the value. However, I want my checkboxes to have the correct value as well, so that I can use this data on the back end.

**Question**
What do I need to modify in either my form declaration or template to correctly render HTML for this check box group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinct `id` on `checkbox` on the definition on field add attribute id:

```
form.Checkbox('search_continent', value='South America', id="Africa")
```